# Built-in camera not working Ubuntu 21.10 + Lenovo E40-70

Tags: drivers, webcam, 21.10

I have problems with my built-in camera, I've been looking at. It doesn't work with cheese nor any other programs and it worked fine with windows. The programs recognize the cam as Lenovo EasyCam but they are not able to use it. I think it's the Acer device of the lsusb output. Any ideas?

```
nurali_dev@nurali:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 138a:0011 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS5011 Fingerprint Reader
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0cf3:3004 Qualcomm Atheros Communications AR3012 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 24ae:2013 Shenzhen Rapoo Technology Co., Ltd. Rapoo 2.4G Wireless Device
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Do you get resolution to above issue , Same issue is coming on my Dell laptop latitude 9420